# How to eliminate (hide) output numbers in a slide show

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting

I am creating a slide show with several imbedded `Manipulate` objects.  I can hide the `Manipulate` command by clicking on the output cell bracket.  I would like to eliminate (or to hide automatically generated output number, e.g. `Out[2] = ...`.
  Is there a notebook level option to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Go To **Format > Edit Stylesheet...** and add this style to your private stylesheet:

```
Cell[StyleData["Output", "SlideShow"],
 ShowCellLabel->False]
```

Answer (score 2):

"Show In/Out Names" in the Edit menu -> Preferences under "Evaluation".